# Auto-filling In Excel

Tags: excel, autofill

I have a data set that looks as follows:

[image: as follows]

I would like to fill the empty cells in column A with the names of the respective countries.

Can I do it automatically in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

> Under presumption cell A1 always starts with a country and the data in column B is always complete (last cell always has value)

```
Private Sub fill_countries()
    Dim tmp as Variant
    Dim lr as Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For each cell in Columns(1).Cells
       If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
           tmp = cell.Value
       End If
       cell.Value = tmp

       If cell.Row = lr Then 'safety measure so we don't end up with endless loops _
                              after going through last data item
          Exit For
       End If

    Next cell
End Sub
```

Data:

[image]

Output after macro (as expected):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this answer. is relating to exactly your need.

https://superuser.com/questions/603318/in-excel-how-do-you-auto-fill-until-next-value/603329.

For your convenience steps listed below.

Under presumption cell A1 always starts with a country

1. Ctrl + A (Select All)
2. Press F5
3. Select Special
4. Select Blanks
5. Press = then arrowUp then enterKey